# C - Assembler message

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, x86-64, bsp

I'm trying to compile a BSP program written in C, and I'm getting this weird error message:

```
/tmp/ccEDn8lx.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccEDn8lx.s:141: Error: illegal immediate register operand (%rip)
```

Code: http://pastebin.com/cuz026ji

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: what are you compiling for? intel x64? for a 64 bit machine, on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: @Aniket It's a remote unix server, any idea how I can figure out which is it?

Comment: "uname -a" will give you an indication of what version of unix it is. It seems rather strange, because the assembler is called by the compiler, so it's almost like the assembler is the wrong one for the compiler...

Comment: @Smoopy: what is mcbsp.h, and how do you compile?

Comment: @MatsPetersson There could be inline assembly embedded in C/C++ code and that could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error pop up when I tried to compile on a remote unix server as well. My cpp file would compile elsewhere, but on the remote unix serve it would spit out the same error message: illegal immediate register operand (%rip). It turns out that I was trying to use a character that wasn't allowed. That is, I had "$" as a variable, once I replaced this it would compile.